# MySQL error When Update the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$column = "`0907001`='0',`0907002`='0',`0907003`='0',`0907004`='0',`0907005`='0'";
$date="01/01/2013";   
$sql_cmd = "UPDATE `$database`.`$table` SET ($column) WHERE `$table`.`Date` = '$date'";
if(!mysql_query($sql_cmd)) {
  die('inside AddUserToDataBase Error: ' . mysql_error());                      
}
```

Here I got an error
the error is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`0907001`='0',`0907002`='0',`0907003`='0',`0907004`='0',`0907005`='0') WHERE `C' at line 1
```

Please Help....
How can I solve this problem........

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the `(` `)` around `$columns` in the query:

```
$sql_cmd = "UPDATE `$database`.`$table` SET $column WHERE `$table`.`Date` = '$date'";
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Look at his declaration for `$column`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal `$column` will get replaced by the columns list a few lines earlier. So in total the query should be fine then.

Comment: @ColinMorelli,  Sirko Sorry guys - didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis around the columns. Instead of:

`UPDATE TABLE table SET (column = value)`

It should be

`UPDATE TABLE table SET column = value`